# Calculus: tricky integration problem.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Given that $\int_{10}^{\infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{x^3 - x} \mathrm d{x} = K$, find all nonconstant $f(x)$ that satisfy the equality.

I attempted intergration by parts but it seems not to be yielding anything ?

Comment: Can such a question be solved with Wolfram ? I'm still new to the software.

Comment: consider $f(x) = (x^3-x)g(x)$, and now figure out what $g(x)$ could be.

Comment: @Thoth, thank you for the suggestion, but how would that help, since we would now have to integrate $g(x)$, which we don't know ?

Comment: There are a great many $f(x)$ that will work, there is even a constant function that will.

Comment: you're overthinking this, there are many $g(x)$ which will work, all you need to do is find one.  Use the fact that you can pull constants outside the integral.

Comment: There is infinitely many solutions, do  you need just 1 or all of the solutions?

Comment: @user26977, we indeed require all of the solutions, as edited. Thanks for pointing that out, had overlooked it.

Comment: You can take for example $g(x) = e^{c x}$ and find suitable $c<0$ as a function of K. Then you can take a linear combination of any number of exponential functions and find another family of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $K=0$ and let $V$ be the space of all such functions $g(x)$. It is easy to prove that $V$ is a vector space. Take an exponential function as a particular solution and you get that all solutions of your equation form an affine space. This space is certainly infinite-dimensional.